# Как добавить описание элементам enum в C#?

Tags: c#, enum

Есть описанное перечисление. Например:

```
public enum Duration { S , D, F }
```

Необходимо, чтобы в сплывающих подсказках автозаполнения было описание каждого элемента..

Вот как это выглядит сейчас.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы, чтобы выглядело как тут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В сплывающей подсказке поясняется что означает данный элемент перечисления. Как подобное описание добавить к своим enum?

Нужно, чтобы описание было доступно в стороннем проекте при подключении данного (переносимая библиотека) в виде собранного dll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы документация из внешней dll работала в сторонних проектах, необходимо включить генерацию XML-документа при сборке.

> По умолчанию создание xml-файла из комментариев отключено. Его нужно
>   включить в свойствах проекта на вкладке Build.
>
> В результате при компиляции, в дополнение к файлу вашей сборки, будет 
>   сгенерирован
>   xml-файл, который содержит все xml-комментарии из кода (в том числе
>   комментарии к непубличным структурам). Этот файл уже сам по себе
>   полезен тем, что если его положить рядом со сборкой (вашей dll), то
>   это позволит функции IntelliSense в Visual Studio отображать описания
>   для методов в момент набора пользователем кода.

Информация взята из статьи: https://habrahabr.ru/post/102177/
Там также есть прочая полезная инфа по составлению документации на C#

Comment: Если вы пишете проект и в вашем же проекте создадите xml комментарии, то они у вас начинают работать сразу, для этого даже не надо создавать xml-файл при компиляции. Обратите внимание на ответ @VladD

Comment: @Bulson, суть в том, что мне было нужно, чтобы комментарии из переносимой библиотеки были видны в другом проекте, в котором я просто подключаю собранную dll.

Comment: А ну в этом случае, так. В вашем вопросе изначально не было никакой информации о том, что вы пишете библиотеку для других. Потому я и оставил такой комментарий.

Comment: @Bulson, потому что, когда задавал вопрос, не знал, что для библиотеки в этом плане есть свои особенности.

Answer (score 11):

```
public enum Duration
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Text
    /// </summary>
    S,
    /// <summary>
    /// Text
    /// </summary>
    D,
    /// <summary>
    /// Text
    /// </summary>
    F
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Вот так:

```
public enum Duration
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Это S
    /// </summary>
    S,
    /// <summary>
    /// А вот это D
    /// </summary>
    D,
    /// <summary>
    /// А вот тут вообще F
    /// </summary>
    F
}
```

[image: все любят картинки]

Comment: У меня почему-то не выводит =(

Comment: @Mr.Modest: А вы поставили именно тройной слеш?

Comment: да.. вот так: http://pastexen.com/code.php?file=L0sTRPT8Si.cs

Comment: посмотрите по ссылке.. SO вёрстку похерил, поэтому я дал ссылку на листинг

Comment: @Mr.Modest: С вашим кодом выходит так: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C62h2.png. А вы держите мышку точно над `S`?

Comment: у меня enum в одном проекте (Переносимая библиотека классов). Я собираю dll и подключаю к консольному приложению.. и пытаюсь использовать там.. описания нет =/

Comment: @Mr.Modest: А если в коде библиотеки попробовать?

Comment: http://pastexen.com/i/SL6tx3T4Eu.png - в самой библиотеке всё норм, но мне надо, чтобы описание работало при подключении dll к другим проектам, а там только это -> http://pastexen.com/i/iKbZ4z2zdU.png

Comment: @Mr.Modest: Окей, это уже интереснее.

Comment: @Mr.Modest: Странно, у меня и так работает тоже: https://i.stack.imgur.com/agwDO.png

Comment: @Mr.Modest: А вы случайно не меняли настройки проекта вручную? Да, и как вы подключаете DLL библиотеки? Это может быть важно.

Comment: В обозревателе решений ПКМ по "Ссылки" - "Добавить ссылку" - "Обзор" - выбираю dll - ОК

Comment: @Mr.Modest: А если через Ссылки -> Проекты -> выбрать проект?

Comment: Разобрался.. Помогла вот эта статья -> https://habrahabr.ru/post/102177/
Вкратце: надо было включить в свойствах сборки создание xml-документации, а потом поместить созданный при сборке xml рядом с dll, где используется..

Comment: @Mr.Modest: А, ну да, или так. Но всё же если вы подключаете через Проекты -> выбор проекта, это не должно быть нужно.

Comment: я принципиально не хотел связывать проекты, чтобы было видно как новый проект будет вести себя, если ему скормить только собранный dll и ничего более..

Comment: @Mr.Modest: Ну, это была важная информация :) Без этого, как видите, всё работает.

Comment: можете дополнить свой ответ и я отмечу его правильным)

Comment: @Mr.Modest: Ну, решение же нашли вы сами? Имеет смысл написать его ответом.